# Set Canonical URL to GIF for Facebook

Tags: facebook

I'm creating a gif hosting user frontend submission site. For Facebook to correctly animate a GIF on their platform, the og meta tag needs to be redirected to the specific gif. I can remedy this by manually adding the gif url as the canonical link and it will work.

However, dynamic posts from multiple users, I will need to reference that gif as canonical in order for it to work.

What would be the best method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I learned that OG:URL tags can be the workaround and can work completely away from canonical links. That said I had to clean out an existing opengraph url that pointed to OG:URL and create a new one based on the posted thumbnail of the gif.

This was added to my `function.php` file

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_opengraph_url' , '__return_false' ); 
add_action('wp_head', 'dgsoft_fb'); function dgsoft_fb(){
if( is_single() ) {
         echo '<meta property="og:url" content="'. get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full')   .'" />';
       } }
```